# How to find center of native cursor and align the custom cursor to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a custom cursor using two div elements, both of them are circles. First one is the main cursor and other one is its follower. They use jQuery to track mouse coordinates. My problem is, when the cursor is not moving I want to make both look like concentric circles(both circle have same center) but they are not at center. I have tried it using (e.PageX -(offset - radius of circle)) but it doesn't return any value.
I am not able to explain this properly sorry new here, I have linked the codepen below:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
 $('#cursor').css({
   "left" : (e.pageX + 'px'),
   "top" : (e.pageY   + 'px')
    });
$('#cursorFollow').css({
   "left" : (e.pageX + 'px'),
   "top" : (e.pageY   + 'px')
});
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Neil98/pen/JevKmV?editors=0110)

Comment: Can you show what you tried? It works for me when I change the positions in the codepen to, e.g. `((e.pageX-6) + 'px')`.

Comment: @MrLister Yes it works when you subtract pixels but I was looking for a more perfect way. I tried subtracting the (offset - radius) from the e.Page coordinates each. But it doesn't return any values, it returns NaN. Anyways got the solution below, Thanks for contributing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is you are getting the `left` and `top` of the cursor's point to set the position of both circle and one is smaller than other so they are being painted from that exact position

If you want to center the circle to the pointer of the cursor use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` in both element it will move the circles half its size in both directions (center)

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
     $('#cursor').css({
       "left" : (e.pageX + 'px'),
       "top" : (e.pageY   + 'px')
   });
    $('#cursorFollow').css({
       "left" : (e.pageX + 'px'),
       "top" : (e.pageY   + 'px')
    });
    });
```

```css
*{
/*   cursor:none; */
}
body{
  height: 300vh;
}
.cursor{
    position: absolute;
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);     //new
}
.cursor-follower{
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.4;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
    pointer-events: none;
    will-change: all;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);       //new
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor" id="cursor"></div>
        <div class="cursor-follower" id="cursorFollow"></div>
```

[Here a working pen](https://codepen.io/yandylvl/pen/NEMRQe)

If you want a diferente centering please add an img of what is your desired result

Comment: Oh yes this is what I wanted, Thanks a lot. Simple yet clever solution.

Comment: Why is it laggy by the way? I used will-change to the cursorFollow, I guess that should make it smooth, right ??

Comment: @Ryuzaki98 it is laggy because the `transition: 0.2s ease-out;` that makes it take 0.2 seconds to reach the cursor and the `ease-out` make it fast/abrupt at the beginning, slow at the end, check this https://css-tricks.com/ease-out-in-ease-in-out/ to a better understand in `transition-timing-function` Can you please upvote the answer too?

Comment: Yes i saw that i have put the transition on purpose that issue is solved it was just my computer's problem and yes i have upvoted the answer but i have reputation less than 15 so it isn't visible